# Messed up progress bars when installing npm packages inside ansi-term

Tags: emacs, npm

I use ansi-term for all my npm and yeoman needs because it sometimes shows up dialogs that shell-mode cannot handle. It works pretty well, until I installed a package and it showed up a messed up download progress bar. Pardon the ugly output, but it looks like this:

> pngquant-bin@0.1.6 postinstall /Users/avendael/tmp/yo-angular/node_modules/pngquant-bin
>   node lib/check.js
>
> pngquant: downloading [                   ] 3% 0.0s   pngquant:
>   downloading [                   ] 3% 0.2s   pngquant: downloading [
>   ] 6% 6.7s   pngquant: downloading [                   ]  6% 6.2s
>   pngquant: downloading [=                  ] 9% 8.2s   pngquant:
>   downloading [=                  ] 10% 7.6s   pngquant: downloading [= 
>   ] 12% 7.6s   pngquant: downloading [==
>            ] 13% 8.2s   pngquant: downloading [==                 ] 15% 7.0s   pngquant: downloading [==                 ] 16% 6.9s   pngquant: downloading [===                ] 19% 6.8s   pngquant:
>   downloading  [===                ] 19% 7.1s   pngquant: downloading
>   [===                ] 22% 6.5s   pngquant: downloading [====
>   ] 23% 6.2s   pngquant: downloading [====               ] 25% 6.4s
>   pngquant:  downloading [====               ] 26% 6.3s   pngquant:
>   downloading [=====              ] 28% 5.9s   pngquant: downloading
>   [=====              ] 29% 6.3s   pngquant: downloading [=====
>   ] 31% 6.0   pngquant: downloading [=====              ] 32% 5.9s
>   pngquant: downloading [======             ] 34% 5.7s   pngquant:
>   downloading [======             ] 36% 5.6s   pngquant: downloading
>   [=======             ] 38% 5.5s   pngquant: downloading [=======
>   ] 39% 5.3s   pngquant: downloading [=======            ] 41% 5.2s
>   pngquant: downloading [=======            ] 42% 5.1s   pngquant:
>   downloading [=======
>   =           ] 44% 4.9s   pngquant: downloading [========           ] 45% 4.7s   pngquant: downloading [========           ] 47% 4.6s
>   pngquant: downloading [=========          ] 49% 4.5s   pngquant:
>   download ing [=========          ] 50% 4.3s   pngquant: downloading
>   [=========          ] 52% 4.1s   pngquant: downloading [==========
>   ] 53% 4.0s   pngquant: downloading [==========         ] 55% 3.8s
>   pngqua nt: downloading [==========         ] 57% 3.7s   pngquant:
>   downloading [===========        ] 58% 3.5s   pngquant: downloading
>   [===========        ] 60% 3.4s   pngquant: downloading [===========
>   ] 62% 3 .2s   pngquant: downloading [============       ] 63% 3.1s
>   pngquant: downloading [============       ] 65% 2.9s   pngquant:
>   downloading [============       ] 66% 2.8s   pngquant: downloading
>   [============= 
>        ] 68% 2.6s   pngquant: downloading [=============      ] 69% 2.5s   pngquant: downloading [=============      ] 71% 2.3s   pngquant:
>   downloading [==============     ] 73% 2.2s   pngquant: downloading [==
>   ============     ] 75% 2.0s   pngquant: downloading [==============     ] 76% 1.9s   pngquant: downloading [===============    ] 78% 1.7s
>   pngquant: downloading [===============    ] 79% 1.6s   pngquant: dow
>   nloading [===============    ] 81% 1.4s   pngquant: downloading
>   [===============    ] 82% 1.3s   pngquant: downloading
>   [================   ] 84% 1.2s   pngquant: downloading
>   [================   ] 85% 1.1s   p ngquant: downloading
>   [=================  ] 92% 0.6s   pngquant: downloading
>   [===================] 98% 0.1s   pngquant: downloading
>   [===================] 100% 0.0s
>
> ✓ pre-build test passed successfully pngquant-bin@0.1.6
>   node_modules/pngquant-bin

I tried it out in a terminal and it looks like a normal progress bar, with bars moving to the right as the download goes on.

I also tried installing the same package inside shell-mode, and the output (again, pardon the ugliness) looks like this:

> pngquant-bin@0.1.6 postinstall /Users/avendael/tmp/yo-angular/node_modules/pngquant-bin
>   node lib/check.js
>
> [1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [                   ] 3%
>   0.0s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [                   ] 3% 0.2s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [                   ] 6% 8.7s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [                   ] 6% 8.0s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=                  ] 9% 6.2s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=                  ] 10% 5.7s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=                  ] 12% 4.9s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [==                 ] 13% 4.6s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [==                 ] 15% 6.2s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [==                 ] 16% 5.9s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [===                ] 19% 5.3s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [===                ] 19% 5.0s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [===                ] 22% 4.6s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [====               ] 23% 4.4s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [====               ] 25% 6.1s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [====               ] 26% 5.8s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=====              ] 32% 4.4s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=======            ] 39% 3.3s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=======            ] 41% 3.2s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=======            ] 42% 3.1s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [========           ] 44% 2.9s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [========           ] 45% 2.8s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [========           ] 47% 2.7s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=========          ] 49% 2.6s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=========          ] 50% 2.5s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=========          ] 52% 2.5s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [==========         ] 53% 2.4s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [==========         ] 55% 2.2s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [==========         ] 57% 2.1s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [===========        ] 58% 2.0s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [===========        ] 60% 2.0s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [===========        ] 62% 1.9s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [============       ] 63% 1.8s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [============       ] 65% 1.7s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [============       ] 66% 1.6s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=============      ] 68% 1.5s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=============      ] 69% 1.5s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=============      ] 71% 1.3s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [==============     ] 73% 1.3s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [==============     ] 75% 1.2s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [==============     ] 76% 1.1s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [===============    ] 78% 1.0s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [===============    ] 79% 1.0s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [===============    ] 81% 0.9s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [===============    ] 82% 0.8s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [================   ] 84% 0.7s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [================   ] 85% 0.7s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=================  ] 88% 0.6s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=================  ] 88% 0.5s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=================  ] 91% 0.4s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [=================  ] 92% 0.4s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [================== ] 94% 0.3s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [================== ] 95% 0.2s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [================== ] 97% 0.1s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [===================] 98% 0.1s[1G[0J [1G  pngquant: downloading [===================] 100% 0.0s
>
> ✓ pre-build test passed successfully

It's pretty much the same but this time, there's a `^[[1G^[[0J ^[[1G` after each bar. Any idea what's causing this?

Here's how ansi-terms stty looks like:

```
speed 9600 baud;
lflags: echoe echoke echoctl pendin
oflags: -oxtabs
cflags: cs8 -parenb
erase   kill    
<undef> <undef>
```

shell-mode looks like this:

```
speed 9600 baud;
lflags: -echo echoe echoke echoctl
oflags: -onlcr -oxtabs
cflags: cs8 -parenb
erase   kill    
<undef> <undef>
```

osx terminal's stty:

```
speed 9600 baud;
lflags: -echo echoe echoke echoctl
oflags: -onlcr -oxtabs
cflags: cs8 -parenb
erase   kill    
<undef> <undef>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the spinner.  The easiest way to do this is:

```
$ npm config set spin false
```

If colour is a problem:

```
$ npm config set color false
```

Finally, if you have issues with your JavaScript prompt:

```
$ export NODE_NO_READLINE=1
$ node
>
```

Hope this helps.